# JavaScript is duplicating elements returned by document get methods when I run the returned element collection through a loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I need to iterate over three input fields; all three share the same class and all three have the same grandparent element with a unique id.

```
<div id="layout-fields">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4 layout-input-field-container">
            <input class="layout-input-fields" id="id_layout_1" maxlength="50" name="layout_1" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 layout-input-field-container">
            <input class="layout-input-fields" id="id_layout_2" maxlength="50" name="layout_2" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 layout-input-field-container">
            <input class="layout-input-fields" id="id_layout_3" maxlength="50" name="layout_3" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When a user clicks on a set of icons, the following event handler is invoked:

```
$(".layout-icons").click(function(){
    selectLayout(this);
});
```

Which calls this method (shortened to relevant code):

```
var selectLayout = function(obj){
    var selectedLayoutValue = $(obj).siblings(".layout-image-description").text();
    var layout_fields_container = document.getElementsByClassName('layout-input-fields');
    var filledInputs = 0;
    var selectedValueAlreadyAssignedInputField = false;

    console.log(layout_fields_container.length);

    for(lfc in layout_fields_container){
        console.log(layout_fields_container[lfc]);
        if(layout_fields_container[lfc].value == selectedLayoutValue) {
            selectedValueAlreadyAssignedInputField = true;
            layout_fields_container[lfc].value = '';

        if(layout_fields_container[lfc].value != '' && typeof layout_fields_container[lfc].value !== "undefined"){
            if(layout_fields_container[lfc].value.length > 0){
                filledInputs++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ok here is the issue. The console log say that layout_fields_container.length = 3. So that makes sense. But the for loop iterates 12 times! What exactly is it iterating over and how can I restrict it just to the input elements?

Here is exactly how it executes:

1. Does a clean run through three input fields so the console log cleanly shows field1, field2, field3. That initial console log statement shows that the length of layout_fields_container is 3
2. When the loop is finished it apparently goes back to the beginning of the selectLayout method. So that initial console.log is called and the length is still 3.
3. It goes back into the loop again, this time it iterates through each input field twice. So the console.log prints, in the for loop field1, field1, field2, field2, field3, field3
4. Still in the loop, it prints two additional lines 1) "function item() { [native code] } and 2) function namedItem() { [native code] }

Why is it going back through the loop? And where are these extra items in the collection coming from?

Comment: Wow. Such inconsistency. Much bug. Do loop. So Jquerascript.

Comment: Besides the solution Jon provided, could you please explain those other bugs you're talking about? I would love to fix them but I need to know what they are first.

Comment: sorry I just love the Doge meme! You don't have bugs so much as it's just inconsistent coding style. You set one variable with jQuery, and the next with JS, you name one with CamelCase, the next with under_score. In your `if` statement you compare with loose (!=) & strict (!==) (strict is the way to go).Then you want the `typeof` of a value (redundant check)... that will always return `String`, never 'undefined'. And you use `this` in a jquery function instead of `$(this)` (which allows event delegation). But the whole function is pointless, your second if will never fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over something with `for...in`. That is the wrong thing to do an alarming percentage of the time, and it's also wrong here: you will also iterate over non-numeric indexes as well.

Convert your loop to a standard `for`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < layout_fields_container.length; ++i) {
     // do stuff with layout_fields_container[i]
}
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you. But why does the length come back with 3 when there are more items in the collection? I'm assuming those non-numeric indexes are items in the list?

Comment: @BrianKempf: No, they are properties on the object. Try this: `var arr = [0, 1, 2]; arr.whatever = "surprise!";` and then `for...in` over `arr`. You will get the key `whatever` in addition to the obvious indexes.

Comment: Oh that makes sense; I was reading the documentation incorrectly, obviously. Thank you

Comment: one more question. 9/12 of the iterations were over the items in the collection. I intended to have 3 items in the collection (the .length returned 3). Why did it repeat iterating over the items two further times?

Comment: @BrianKempf: Perhaps you accidentally nested the loop? 3 * 3 = 9?